# Stopping Criteria for Pre-Training using Stacked Autoencoders

Tags: deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, autoencoders, pre-training

In stacked autoencoders during greed layer-wise training of individual autoencoders using gradient descent and backpropagation to minimize the reconstruction error(squared error or cross entropy) what is the ideal stopping criteria for the pre-training ?

Is it when a minimum reconstruction error is achieved or some other criteria ?

Comment: Convergence of reconstruction error can be good measure. Convergence shows that the network can't get better overtime so there is not much point to continue training.

Comment: Can you state a quantifiable measure of what is the optimal reconstruction error % which should be attained by the network ?

Comment: Optimal error depends on the data. What I'm saying is monitor reconstruction error (cost function). As weight captures more common structures, the error will decrease. After some time, error converges to some value and can't decrease anymore. That is an ideal stopping criteria.

Comment: @yasin.yazici This is a good sign to stop training, but how do you know if the error achieved is low enough for the whole classifier network, or that you should try a different autoencoder config? Is there a rule of thumb that would save you from trying every autoencoder/classifier layout?

Comment: @jwalker Early stopping find optimum error rate for specific network config (hyperparameters). You should try greedy grid search or bayesian optimization to find optimum hyperparameters. You can make some guess about number of layers and hidden neurons based on complexity of the problem. If you need detailed explanation read this paper. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533v2.pdf Especially the title "Hyper-Parameters"

Comment: @yasin.yazici The problem I'm talking about is not about how you can improve the results, it's do you really need to. The reason is that with autoencoders and layer by layer training you have so many options to try. So it would be helpful to know if the reconstruction error level you're getting is "good enough" to go ahead and try attaching the classifier.

Comment: @jwalker: Fairly sure knowing when pretraining is suffient is unknowable, and that for some problems pretraining will be worse than not pretraining at all.
As wall sas the Grid search and bayesian optimisation yasin suggests, I have used a Particle Swarm Optimiser  to search my hyperparameters. I'm sure there are a few papers about that.
But it comes down to early stopping. 

If one had the time, it would be better to early stop over the Classification error, rather than the pretraining error.
There is a reason this is call "Greedy layerwise Pretraining"